# Internet always cuts out

Tags: networking, ssh, web-server, apache-httpd

I'm using my Raspberry Pi to set up a simple Apache Web Server using [these](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server) instructions.
The problem I am having is that the Web Server will come up for a little while but then seem to just stop working. I have connected my Raspberry Pi to the internet via an ethernet cable hooked up to my router.

I have sorted out forwarding of ports so that I can navigate to pi.mywebsite.com and it works fine. However, it works fine for about a minute after booting, then it just stops; ifconfig.me doesn't work and even accessing the Raspberry Pi over SSH doesn't work.

**More information:** When the Raspberry Pi stops being able to connect to the internet the Pi still works fine. I can hook it up to a monitor and keyboard and fiddle about with commands and stuff. It doesn't even seem that hot (it has been a lot warmer and not crashed before).

**Even more information:** My Raspberry Pi is overclocked at the Modest setting and the GPU was given 128Mb.

When it cuts out and I run `curl ifconfig.me` the following is outputted:

```
curl (6) couldn't resolve host 'ifconfig.me'
```

Here is the output when I run `ifconfig`. Sorry about the quality. It's legible.

[image]

Why is this? And is there anything I can do to stop this error from happening?

Comment: can you post your `ifconfig` output after the internet is gone? also, network related entries from `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/dmesg` would be nice to see (not the whole files, just network-related things).

Comment: Well this is so odd. It's been about 15 minutes and no crash. Hmmm... I'll leave it another 10-15 minutes.

Comment: @lenik I've added the `ifconfig` output. Logs coming soon...

Comment: How do I determine what logs are network related? Or should I just upload them somewhere and let you look through them?

Comment: please, run the command at the prompt: `ifconfig` (no curl, no nothing else)

Comment: @lenik Sorry about that. I've added the `ifconfig` command output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the Raspberry Pi (or the Raspbian distro) cuts out the internet after a period of inactivity.

This is easily fixed with the following cron job:

```
* * * * * ping -c 1 www.google.com
```

Comment: thats wierd. It does not do that on mine- running for 3 weeks now and never dropped the connection?

Comment: Hmm... Might just be a bug with my router or something... Who knows eh!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly try and update to the latest firmware.

```
sudo apt-get install rpi-update
sudo rpi-update
#once complete reboot the Pi
```

After reboot just to make sure do repo update

```
apt-get update
```

Try and put the over-clock mode into normal position and set the GPU RAM to 32MB on Model B and on Model A put it to 8MB. If it is going to run headless you don't need GPU RAM.

Try and use some networking patches. in /etc/sysctl.conf

```
vm.min_free_kbytes = 8192
```

if the problem still continues try

```
smsc95xx.turbo_mode=N
```

Sometimes USB devices clash with the Network (Because network is connected via USB) Try and disconnect all USB devices.

A massive pain in the neck are SD cards. They might seem fine to write and read but sometimes they just do not want to work. [Try and get a recommended SD card](http://elinux.org/index.php?title=RPiconfig&section=14%7CSD) - I have experienced issues with SD, MMC and even normal USB drives acting as Operating System drives on various hardware and using hand full of different OS's. Just get a few different ones.

Try and use a completely different power supply. Just because it says 1A does not mean it can really handle it. Some el cheap'os are a pain in the but and after a few hours start to loose power because of poor design. [The best power supply is a switching power supply for about 5~15 bucks delivered](http://dx.com/s/12v+Regulated+Switching+Power+Supply.html?sort=Price). They are also more power efficient.

I doubt Apache is the root of the problem but lets tickle our fancy; Try go and install the base version of nginx (engine-x) Make sure you stop a-patch-me first to free port 80. *(Its is allot faster than a-patch-me anyway and you can compile allot of cool things into it)*

```
apt-get install nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

I set up networking in a hurry following this wiki on how to setup the /etc/network/interfaces that I got from [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration) which confused the bejayshus out of me even though i've been setting up networks for years.

This problem is caused by incorrect configuration of the /etc/network/interfaces. Assuming that you have a wired connection,

Try using a configuration like:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.4
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
up route add default gw 192.168.1.1
down route del default gw 192.168.1.1
```

This I found worked for me as a starting network configuration template. You will need to alter the ip addresses appropriately for your network. If you use DHCP, try:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I hope that is enough to get you started. After changing these settings and rebooting the raspberry pi, the problem disappeared.